# How to execute Jenkins shared library functions on slave instead of master?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries

I need to  write shared library that reads files in build workspace and shared library functions cannot read files because pipeline is on slave and shared library is executed in master. Is there any way tho change execution context of library functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out answer. You can read library file and give the file to writeFile pipeline step

```
writeFile(file:"foo.groovy", text: libraryResource("bar.groovy"))
"groovy foo.groovy"
```

writeFile neads BOTH parameters as named parameters so answer given in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54646 is not fully right.

Comment: Where should we add these lines ???

Answer (score 1):

To execute Jenkins shared library functions on slave instead of master. You can  implement de argument node("slaveName") in the call:

```
def call(Map config=[:], Closure body) {
 
def  label = 'slave'
node("${label}") {  
    
    pipeline { 

            stage('Sonarqube') {
              
                  script {
                  withSonarQubeEnv('Sonar8') {
                    withMaven(maven: 'apache-maven') { 
                            sh 'mvn sonar:sonar -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dsonar.java.binaries=./target' 
                    }
                  }
                  }
             }//pipeline
```

} // call

Answer (score 0):

You Can actually do it without writeFile, This shared Library Code will be executed in Master, but it will use RemoteDignostic to Execute commands to Slave
to execute `uname -a` in worker node

```
import hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics
import jenkins.model.Jenkins


class test_exec{
  def env
  def propertiesFilePath
  @NonCPS
    def call(cmd) {
          def trial_script = """
                   println "uname -a".execute().text
            """.trim()
        String result
  
Jenkins.instance.slaves.find { agent ->
    agent.name == "${env.NODE_NAME}"
}.with { agent ->
    result = RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(trial_script, agent.channel)
}
      return result
}

}
```

In your pipeline

```
steps{
println(new test_exec().call())
}
```